# Schematics of photodiode BPW34 interfacing with an ADC ESP32

Tags: operational-amplifier, adc, photodiode, transimpedance-amplifier

I am designing a circuit that uses a [BPW34](https://www.vishay.com/docs/81521/bpw34.pdf) photodiode for visible light communication. The transmission distance is about 5-6 m, and the transmission frequency is only about 1-10 kHz.

I have consulted this circuit and don't know how accurate it is.

1. Is there something wrong with my design?

[image]

2. For the circuit to work properly I need to change something, but what?

Comment: But if you just copied that design it's not yours. Have you tried it? You can buy that module for about a dollar. There may not be anything wrong with it, another thing is if it works or not for your purposes.

Comment: I only design based on existing designs, and don't know how to calculate components for the circuit, this is not a commercial circuit so I can't buy it. Will there be any visible flaws found?

Comment: An unfiltered BPW34 is sensitive to daylight: will you use it in total darkness? Otherwise, assuming your *transmission* is IR, a BPW34F would be better suited. Then about the amplifier, the gain is just 100mV/uA: is your transmission source strong enough? Don't forget then the offset voltage of LM324, which is relatively high. Also, its gain bandwidth isn't that great, depending on the original signal it can affect the result.